# Does one read 行【い】った or 行【おこな】った?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings, collocations

In this sentence...

彼【かれ】の挙動【きょどう】がおかしいので警官【けいかん】がつけて行【い】った

*The policeman followed him because of his suspicious behavior.*

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/挙動#je-18506](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95#je-18506)

...does the verb mean "went" 行【い】った or "did" 行【おこな】った?

I found a similar example sentence in wwwjdic, but without the 行った at the end:

警官【けいかん】はその男【おとこ】をつけた。

*The policeman followed him.*

Comment: Why would this be 行う?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be 行く, not 行う. The latter is used to say something was carried out/executed.

Here, 行く is actually part of the format of ていく. When you add いく to a て-form of a verb, it is as if the verb is currently being acted out.

> In your example, the police were likely to begin a process of following him. To say, the police began to actively follow him. It conveys a sense of progression of some event.

The other used of a directional verb you will see is てくる, which is to say some verb arrived at something, or that something was done, and arrived at that state.

> 太くなってきた would be something became fat after some process, to say it arrived at being fat.